# How do I prevent my program from writing incorrect input to a CSV file?

Tags: python-3.5

I want to input data into a CSV file and have so far accomplished that. The only problem I have now encountered is that when the user inputs the incorrect information to a string only input (eg. name = b12f) the program successfully prompts the user again to enter only strings (eg. name = biff).

However, when I look at the CSV file the incorrect value was recorded instead of the corrected input. How do I correct this?

```
import csv
surname = input('\nSurname:')
surname_checker(surname) #I wrote a seperate function that correctly checks the input to judge if it is correct and reprompt if not
s = surname.capitalize()
with open('Try.csv','a',newline='') as csvfile:
    appendCSV = csv.writer(csvfile)
    appendCSV.writerow([s])
csvfile.close()
```

Outcome if b12f is entered then Biff correctly entered:

```
Surname:b12f

Please define Surname only in letters

Surname:biff
>>> print(surname)
b12f
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not CSV specific. Your use of `print(surname)` should be a sign - it's not doing anything with the CSV file, but it's still printing the wrong thing.

Your custom function needs to return the corrected surname, and you need to replace the stored surname with it.

Something like `surname = surname_checker(surname)`